# How do i FTP in CMD, automate this process?

Tags: cmd, automation, ftp

Im having a problem creating a batch file that will run commands in Windows. If I FTP to the remote device it will work, all user inputs work.

I am hoping to automate this process as it involves user input and i wouldn't want anyone to fat finger it.
so run this as CMD

```
FTP xx.xx.xx.xxx
USERNAME: ftp
PASSWORD: (Blank, No Password, i just press "ENTER")
binary
prompt n
mget *.File extension here
bye
```

All of this is for an isolated network, the device im connecting through FTP accepts the pressing "ENTER" as the input of the password.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Scripting FTP via batch is done as two parts. The .bat file to call FTP itself, and a separate text file containing the commands you want FTP to run, including the authentication credentials.

So for instance within your batch script you'd have

```
ftp -i -s:C:\Scripts\ftp-commands.txt ftpserver.mydomain.com
```

Then within the ftp-commands.txt file

```
myusername
mypassword
hash on
put somefile.doc
get someotherfile.doc
disconnect
quit
```

I've only ever used it to fully automate an FTP connection, normally on a schedule, so not tried using it interactively, but presumably if you ommit the `disconnect` and `quit` from the end of the .txt file you'd be left with the cmd window open and the FTP connection available for the user to provide any required commands.

Note, this obviously all relies on your destination FTP server supporting plain FTP and not requiring it to be SSL secured, since command line FTP doesn't support FTPS.

Comment: The Windows firewall and all other firewalls block also incoming connections as it is done by an FTP server for establishing the data channel to the FTP client after the FTP client connected to the FTP server with establishing the control channel (active mode). Firewalls can be passed by default for FTP server accesses only using passive mode, see the Wikipedia page about [File Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp). But `%SystemRoot%\System32\ftp.exe` does not support passive mode. This program is useless for that reason nowadays on not making changes on firewall rules.

Comment: Good point about Passive FTP also not being available. Can still be useful sometimes for internal transfers within a network or via a VPN (where you can safely ignore the lack of secure FTP connection etc), but I agree I'd never use it for connecting to the general internet.

Comment: @KeithLangmead An oversight on my end. i will look into it. is there a way to bypass the password? There isnt one for the remote device. i just hit enter.

Comment: @jailbarra Honestly have no idea, I'd never NOT have a password set since it's scripted so it's not like someone has to type it in every time.